# Extracting table caption/title from a word document

Tags: python, win32com

I have to extract content of specific tables from a huge msword doc. After some reading, I have been trying to use win32com to extract the table titles. I used the following code.

```
from win32com import client
word = client.Dispatch("Word.Application")
document = word.Documents.Open("path_to_doc")
titles = [table.Title for table in document.Tables]
f = open('myfile.doc', 'w')
f.write("%s" %titles) 
f.close()
```

However the resulting file just has:

```
[u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'']
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Are you sure the document has proper table titles? Can you post one of your tables as an example?

Comment: Hi, Not sure I can post the table here. It looks like a normal word table with the caption at the top "Table 4-12: xxxxxx xxxxxx"